# Django: one ModelForm for subclasses

Tags: python, django

I have an abstract model like this:

```
class BaseAgent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=128, null=False, default='')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I am creating subclasses of this model with exact agent types. For example Agent001, Agent002, whatever.

I would like to have only one class of `ModelForm` form for each of these subclasses. I am going to pass it to the `UpdateView` view. But it requires to have `Meta.model` being specified.

```
class AgentEditForm(ImprovedForm, forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BaseAgent  # here I would like to have Agent001, Agent002 or others
        exclude = ()
```

I have a subclass of `ModelForm` with some mixin added and would like to use this class (lets call it `ImprovedForm`).

Ideally I would like to have one string in `urls.py` to call a view with only model name passed (and form too).

```
url(r'^agent001/new$', login_required(views.AgentCreateUpdateView.as_view(model=Agent001, form=ImprovedAgentForm)), name='new_agent001'),
```

Of course I can create a form for each model like this:

```
class Agent001EditForm(AgentEditForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Agent001
```

But it is just a copy-pasting. Imagine that I have more than two classes and will have more in the future. I'd like to have a generic solution.

How can I do it with minimal lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**forms.py**

```
import sys

for model in (Agent001, Agent002):
    form_name = model.__name__ + 'EditForm'

    class AgentEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = model
            exclude = ()

    AgentEditForm.__name__ = form_name
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], form_name , AgentEditForm)
    del AgentEditForm
```

Comment: Nooo. It's a dirty solution. Not like this!

Comment: You want to perform a dirty thing, but stay clean. Than do it the django way, override forms.

Comment: Another way is to use metaclass or some kind of factory method. It would be acceptable solution and clean from OOD principles. But there should be one more way, closer to Django. Your solution is like 'dirty hack'. It would work, but we both know that we should avoid such things where it is possible. Good example though, thanks.

Comment: I examined the metaclass ModelFormMetaclass before posting the answer. Overriding it is more dirty way. And factory method is not too convenient to use. Also, if you look at the code of ModelFormMetaclass and BaseModelForm, you should see, that there's no clean way to solve the problem. First "sets opts = new_class._meta = ModelFormOptions(getattr(new_class, 'Meta', None))", and secont gets the model from it: "opts = self._meta",  "if opts.model is None: raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.')".
But I agree with you, my approach is a hack. But I can't see more clean way.

Comment: Well, I've just examined django sources too and tried to substitute model in the overloaded metaclass.. And then I realized that it become more dirty indeed. You right, it seems the most straight way is to override forms. Thanks.